# SharePoint Foundation Setup in 32bit

Tags: sharepoint

I have Windows 7 Professional Version OS and i want to Setup SharePoint Foundation in my pc but Sharepoint so can anybody help me to do this ? I need to setup Sharepoint in 32 bit windows7 professional edition.

Answer (score 5):

You can't, SharePoint Foundation requires 64-Bit, no way around it.